# Use emotion css function without exposing the component name in output class name

Tags: reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

Added css to element as below:

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic */
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react';

    function Icon() {
      return (
          <span
              css={css`
                  color: red;
                `}>
              Icon
          </span>
      );
    }
    export default Icon;
```

Class Name generated as **class="css-1f6rj74-Icon"** for the span element.

We don't want to expose component names to public.

How can I **remove the Icon- Component name** from generated css classname.?

- React version: 17.0.2
- "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5"

Comment: based on this https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1365#issuecomment-547160044 , changing injected class name is not supported.